# php json_encode | textos ¿Porqué no los muestra?

Tags: mysql, json

Os dejo mi código:

```
    $sql  = "SELECT id, desc_es FROM descripciones_productos WHERE idproducto<11"; //ESTA SENTENCIA NO MUESTRA NADA
    //$sql  = "SELECT id, nombre, urlfoto FROM productosft WHERE id<11"; //ESTA EN CAMBIO SI MUESTRA

    $modelos = mysql_query($sql, $enlace);

    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($modelos)){ $rowstabla[] = $fila; }
    $rows["estado"] = 1;
    $rows["productos"] = $rowstabla ;
    print json_encode($rows);
```

Os dejo en la parte superior dos sentencias, la segunda que está comentada si funciona, el json la muestra correctamente pero la primera no. Yo creo que es porque en la primera trato con textos que tienen acentos, ñ... y de ahí el error.

Las dos cadenas están probadas en Mysql y funcionan 100%. ¿qué puede pasar?

Por cierto he leido que algunos proponen esta solución

```
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

pero a mi tampoco me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*CASO MYSQLi*

Si estas usando `mysqli` por ejemplo añade dentro de los parámetros; declara que el juego de caracteres es `UTF-8` así mira

```
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
```

Para que interprete de manera correcta los caracteres especiales

*CASO PDO*

```
$conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8", "root", "password");
```

Donde pasas en la primer pareja de comillas:

- el driver `mysql` apuntando a `localhost`
- el nombre de la base de datos
- el tercer parámetro es el `charset` que utilizarás

Comment: añado el por que: "json_encode solo recibe cadenas en UTF-8 o ISO-8859-1."  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694362/1423096

Comment: Gracias Shadow, me sirvió la del PDO y reestructuré un poco el código.